# Getting 404 even when the link works JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to use OpenWeatherMap and get the JSON for the weather.
In the console i see 404 message, but when i visit the url manually it gives me the correct JSON

```js
var latitude;
var longitude;
var apiId = "c440e3f473378f9705827ed71efe5dcc";
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

function getLocation() {

  if (navigator.geolocation) {

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function getPosition(position) {
      latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      getJson();
    });

  } else {
    alert('Geo location not working or not supported by your browser.');
  }

}

function getJson() {

  request.open('GET', "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&APPID=" + apiId + "");

  request.onload = function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  };

  request.send();

}
getLocation();
```

Comment: You are missing a protocol in that url of yours. While we humans understand that this is a uri, and your browser will attempt to correct that  your computer does not know what to do with it. prepend `http://` or `https://` or perhaps even `www`.

Comment: I assume you're testing this locally on your device (and without any local server), this means you must use `https://` or `http://` in beginning of every link, or else it'll just assume it to be `file:///` by default.

Comment: thanks @Saharsh I'm using codepen so i am having problems as OpenWeatherMap uses http, and it is not working

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify `http` at the beginning of your URL

```
request.open('GET', "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&APPID=" + apiId + "");
```

Comment: thanks, but now I'm getting the error that request is blocked as request should be "https". I added it to url and the link doesn't work(I'm using Code pen)

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work?" Are you getting an error?